# How to expose metrics stored in azure tables or Event Hub to prometheus?

Tags: azure, prometheus, azure-eventhub

After following the following guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/diagnostics-linux) I have collected all my vm logs and metrics to a single storage account in a set of tables. I can also set this up to expose the metrics to  Azure Event Hub.

I would now like to expose these metrics to prometheus.

Is there any way of doing this without writing my own scraper that manually pulls the data from azure and exposes it to prometheus?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think there is a straight forward way to do the same. Either you have to create a webjob/function/logic app to expose your data.

However you can use [`Prometheus-Exporter`](https://github.com/discourse/azure-prometheus-exporter) using container to export your data from storage to prometheus.